# Ping to an active directory domain of 4 servers only ever pings one ip address

Tags: networking

We have a domain with 4 ad servers. When I run `ping domain` it always pings the same address and never the other three. Absolutely never. If I run `host domain` the four ip addresses are returned in varying orders, so why do I only see one with `ping`?

Below is a part of what is returned by `strace ping c1 domain`.
There seems to be some type of connection to each of the ip addresses before it selects the one ending in `213`.

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0),sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.57")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(49807), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.242")}, [16]) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.59")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(56595), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.242")}, [16]) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.213")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(38331), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.242")}, [16]) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.56")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(54349), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.242")}, [16]) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.100.213")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46179), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.18.00.242")}, [16]) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_RAW, ICMP_FILTER, ~(1<<ICMP_ECHOREPLY|1<<ICMP_DEST_UNREACH|1<<ICMP_SOURCE_QUENCH|1<<ICMP_REDIRECT|1<<ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED|1<<ICMP_PARAMETERPROB), 4) = 0
```